# SQL finding CTR with nulls

Tags: sql, null, decimal, teradata

I have a table with has many ads, impressions, number clicks

I need to divide the clicks by the impressions.

However, sometimes the impressions is 0 and sometimes the click is 0.
I receive an error when there is a 0.

Also, when I do receive results I get 0. But I want 0.00xxx

I'm using teradata

If I try clicks/impressions I get 'division by zero error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the zeroes when you divide:

```
click/nullif(impressions,0)
```

or you filter

```
where impressions <> 0
```